# Laravel 4 Eloquent getting the site name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables that are related by a foregin key:

Equipment Table

ID primary
Site_ID foregin
UnitNo
Model

Site Table

ID
Sitename

I want to show all the equipment from the equipment table but where is says site_id, I want to show the Site Name.

I am very new to laravel 4 and I am really stuck on how to produce this, my code is as follows:

```
<?php var_dump($equipment); ?>

@foreach($equipment as $item)
<ul>
    <li>{{$item->site_id}}</li>
    <li>{{$item->unitNo}}</li>
    <li>{{$item->Model}}</li>
</ul>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
<?php

class EquipmentController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{

    $equipment = equipment::all();


    return View::make('equipment.index', compact('equipment'));
}
```

Equipment Model

```
<?php
class Equipment extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array();


public function site()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('site', 'site_id');
    }

}
```

Site Model

```
<?php

class Site extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array();


public function equipment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('equipment');
    }

}
```

I am completley lost at this point. Any help help would be apprciated

Thanks

Comment: `$item->site->Sitename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only have to call `$item->site->site_name`. **BUT** for that, your `Equipment Model` has to `belongsTo` Site Model. Other way, it may not work.

```
public function site()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Site');

    }
}
```

The `site_id` key already is on laravel's convention for foreing keys, so you don't **need** to explicity tell him that.

Comment: I eventually realised it should have been belongsTo after the fact!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get it via the relationship?:

```
@foreach($equipment as $item)
<ul>
    <li>{{$item->site->Sitename}}</li>
    <li>{{$item->unitNo}}</li>
    <li>{{$item->Model}}</li>
</ul>
@endforeach
```